# SwiftUI - set the centre of a text view to be in an absolutely fixed position at all times

Tags: swiftui

I am attempting to build a soccer app. My main detail view shows match statistics. I cannot find any way to get the central text element showing the score of the match to stay in the absolute center, so that the colon in the text is perfectly centred over the guideline on the middle of the screen. With different numbers either side of the colon, it gets shifted slightly out of place.

Is there any way to fix this element to be exactly centered under any circumstances? I have attached a screenshot showing the misalignment.

Code:

```
VStack() {
HStack(alignment: .center) {
Text("\(matchItem.HomeGoals) : \(matchItem.AwayGoals)")
.font(.system(size: 35.0))
.fontWeight(.heavy)
.foregroundColor(Color.white)
.lineLimit(3)
.multilineTextAlignment(.center)
.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
.allowsTightening(false)
}.padding(15)
}.frame(width: 75, height: 80, alignment: .center)
```

Example: [image: Misaligned Scoreline]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your View in a ZStack and the ":" on another Z-level, so it no longer depends on other elements in the same horizontal stack.

Comment: Thank you sir. Perfect.